# There should be an option to see Community Wiki questions/answers in your profile.

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, profile-page, sorting

There should be a sorting option for 'Community Wiki' questions/answers in your profile.

This would be helpful, since you don't get notified by the upvotes you get for them.

Comment: I don't understand the conclusion that it should be helpful because CW give no rep. You get notified of posts (comments, answers). That's relevant.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The conclusion is that you don't get notified about the amount of upvotes the question/answer has.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The question/answer, esp. answer, may easily blow up without any comments or other notifications. You may get, say, 50 upvotes on your answer and yet not get a comment. Now your answer turns out to be very helpful and great and yet zero notifications come up.

Comment: ??? May be it comes with high rep, but I do see it on my own page ([in the reputation tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen?tab=reputation)) when my CW-answers have been upvoted. For example (if you see what I see - not sure), my CW-explanation on the meaning of independence of random variables had such an upvote on March 11th. Naturally (no rep points) I won't see that green number on the black bar at the top of the screen.

Comment: I don't think it comes with high rep or being a moderator, @Jyrki. Even when I'm not logged in I can still see the upvote on your profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use-case seems marginal to me, so I do not see a need to have it on the profile, but if you want to know just use search: "user:me wiki:yes" will return all your CW posts; you can further refine the query in various ways.

Side note in view of comments: you would also note major amounts of up-votes arriving via badges.